# python/lists: error with list, but are they not the same?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, jupyter-notebook

so I have this code:

```
li = ['this', 'is', 'an', 'example', 'list']

for i in range(len(li)):
    print(li[i])
```

and the results are just fine. I get what I need.
**but...**
when I run this code:

```
li = ['this', 'is', 'an', 'example', 'list']
for words in li:
    print(li[words])
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
(pretend this is my file path)\test.ipynb Cell 1' in <cell line: 3>()
      1 li = ['this', 'is', 'an', 'example', 'list']
      3 for words in li:
----> 4     print(li[words])

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I am confused... shouldn't this be the same?
I also added `int()` around words and it also didn't work.

Comment: `words` is the element, not the index. Just do `print(words)`

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that when you say `for words in li`, `words` is a `str`, storing the next element of `li` as the `list` is traversed. You can't get a specific object from a `list` by `li[<str>]`; that's not allowed.

When you do `for i in range( len(li) )`, that `range` function effectively generates a list of numbers from 0 up to `len(li)`, and so then you can write `li[i]` because `i` is an `int` and `list` supports indexing using `int`s.